# Remove an item from the Environment variable through powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I don't have a direct access to the Environment Variables on Windows. Therefore I'm trying to remove an item through powershell

```
Remove-Item -Path Env:Path -Value ($Env:Path + ";C:\Item\To\Be\Removed")
```

However getting the error below

[image]

Comment: If I got you right you will have to parse the path, remove the part you want to get rid of and write it completely new.

Comment: This solved my issue actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Powershells perspective the environemnt variable Path is just a long string. So you will have to parse it and use string operations to remove the part you want to get rid of ... maybe like this:

```
$Remove = 'C:\Item\To\Be\Removed'
$env:Path = ($env:Path.Split(';') | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_ -ne $Remove}) -join ';'
```

Additional information about environment variables you can get with [Get-Help about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: This took out all the semicolon separator ; and replaced with spaces?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And one more thing. How do I make the change permanent?

Comment: Therefor you have to choose the "right" environment. If you take a look at the documentation you find with the link I postet you have almost at the bottom of the page an explanation. You have to set it in the user environment or in the machine environment.